# Output before and after the loop

Tags: plugins, loop

I'd like to hook into the loop, ie. have_posts() maybe? and output some code before and after.  Is there a filter for this so I can use it in a plugin without needing to edit themes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function `the_post()` ([source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.5.2/wp-includes/query.php#L2835)) triggers the action `loop_start` when it is first used in the loop. This is used in *every* `WP_Query` loop, so you may want to check if the current query is the 'main' one (assuming that's the query you wish to target)

```
add_action( 'loop_start', 'wpse107113_loop_start' );
function wpse107113_loop_start( $query ){
     if( $query->is_main_query() ){

     }
}
```

The *last time* `have_posts()` is called it triggers the action `loop_end` ([source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.5.2/wp-includes/query.php#L2857)), so similar to above:

```
add_action( 'loop_end', 'wpse107113_loop_end' );
function wpse107113_loop_end( $query ){
     if( $query->is_main_query() ){

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank @Stephen Harris for the above answer :)

Just a very important note, when using the loop start/end you need the code below to prevent unwanted trigger of your code in the head.

```
if ( $query->is_main_query() ):

    ... code here

endif;
```